Error en la configuracion de jetty debido al cambio de version de la 10.0.13 a 12.0.14< exception name="No environment configured">
Hola como estan comunidad
Envio este error que estoy tratando de resolver al migrar mi codigo de la version de jetty 10.0.13 a la 12.0.13.
Adjunto error:
    <exception name="No environment configured">
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: No environment configured
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler$Abstract.doStart(Handler.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.jpos.q2.jetty.Jetty.startService(Jetty.java:79)
    at org.jpos.q2.QBeanSupport.start(QBeanSupport.java:137)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:262)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at org.jpos.q2.QFactory.startQBean(QFactory.java:176)
    at org.jpos.q2.Q2.start(Q2.java:624)
    at org.jpos.q2.Q2.deploy(Q2.java:409)
    at org.jpos.q2.Q2.run(Q2.java:258)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
    </exception>

Codigo de configuracion: jetty.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

    <Get name="ThreadPool">
        <Set name="minThreads" type="int"><Property name="threads.min" default="10"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxThreads" type="int"><Property name="threads.max" default="200"/></Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout" type="int"><Property name="threads.timeout" default="60000"/></Set>
        <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
    </Get>

    <Call name="addBean">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler"/>
        </Arg>
    </Call>

    <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
        <Set name="secureScheme">https</Set>
        <Set name="securePort"><Property name="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" /></Set>
        <Set name="outputBufferSize"><Property name="jetty.output.buffer.size" default="32768" /></Set>
        <Set name="requestHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.request.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
        <Set name="responseHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.response.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
        <Set name="sendServerVersion"><Property name="jetty.send.server.version" default="true" /></Set>
        <Set name="sendDateHeader"><Property name="jetty.send.date.header" default="false" /></Set>
        <Set name="headerCacheSize">512</Set>
        <!-- Uncomment to enable handling of X-Forwarded- style headers
        <Call name="addCustomizer">
          <Arg><New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ForwardedRequestCustomizer"/></Arg>
        </Call>
        -->
    </New>


    <New id="RewriteHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler">
        <Set name="rules">
            <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.Rule">
                <Item>
                    <New id="header-xframe" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.HeaderPatternRule">
                        <Set name="pattern">*</Set>
                        <Set name="headerName">X-Frame-Options</Set>
                        <Set name="headerValue">SAMEORIGIN</Set>
                    </New>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <New id="header-xxss" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.HeaderPatternRule">
                        <Set name="pattern">*</Set>
                        <Set name="headerName">X-XSS-Protection</Set>
                        <Set name="headerValue">1; mode=block</Set>
                    </New>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <New id="header-xcontenttype" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.HeaderPatternRule">
                        <Set name="pattern">*</Set>
                        <Set name="headerName">X-Content-Type-Options</Set>
                        <Set name="headerValue">nosniff</Set>
                    </New>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <New id="header-sts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.HeaderPatternRule">
                        <Set name="pattern">*</Set>
                        <Set name="headerName">Strict-Transport-Security</Set>
                        <Set name="headerValue">max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload</Set>
                    </New>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <New id="header-csp" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.HeaderPatternRule">
                        <Set name="pattern">*</Set>
                        <Set name="headerName">Content-Security-Policy</Set>
                        <Set name="headerValue">default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; frame-ancestors 'self'</Set>
                    </New>
                </Item>
            </Array>
        </Set>
    </New>


    <Set name="handler">
        <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection">
            <Set name="handlers">
                <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
                    <Item>
                        <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <Ref refid="RewriteHandler"/>
                    </Item>
                </Array>
            </Set>
        </New>
    </Set>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- extra server options                                        -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Set name="stopAtShutdown">true</Set>
    <Set name="stopTimeout">5000</Set>
    <Set name="dumpAfterStart"><Property name="jetty.dump.start" default="false"/></Set>
    <Set name="dumpBeforeStop"><Property name="jetty.dump.stop" default="false"/></Set>

    <Call name="addConnector">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
                <Arg name="factories">
                    <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
                        <Item>
                            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                                <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
                            </New>
                        </Item>
                    </Array>
                </Arg>
                <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
                <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8080" /></Set>
                <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="http.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
                <!--          <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="http.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>-->
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>

    <New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory$Server">
        <Set name="KeyStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/cfg/keystore.jks</Set>
        <Set name="ExcludeCipherSuites">
            <Array type="java.lang.String">
                <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5</Item>
                <Item>SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
                <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256</Item>
                <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256</Item>
                <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384</Item>
                <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
                <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256</Item>
                <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256</Item>
                <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384</Item>
                <Item>.NULL.</Item>
                <Item>.RC4.</Item>
                <Item>.MD5.</Item>
                <Item>.DES.</Item>
                <Item>.DSS.</Item>
                <Item>TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
                <Item>TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
            </Array>
        </Set>
        <Set name="ExcludeProtocols">
            <Array type="java.lang.String">
                <Item>SSLv3</Item>
                <Item>TLSv1</Item>
            </Array>
        </Set>
    </New>

    <Call name="addConnector">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
                <Arg name="factories">
                    <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
                        <Item>
                            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory">
                                <Arg name="next">http/1.1</Arg>
                                <Arg name="sslContextFactory"><Ref refid="sslContextFactory"/></Arg>
                            </New>
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                                <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
                            </New>
                        </Item>
                    </Array>
                </Arg>
                <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
                <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" /></Set>
                <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="http.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
                <!--                <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="http.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>-->
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>

    <!--    <Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log" name="getRootLogger">-->
    <!--      <Call name="setDebugEnabled">-->
    <!--        <Arg type="boolean">true</Arg>-->
    <!--      </Call>-->
    <!--    </Call>-->

    <!--    <Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration$ClassList" name="setServerDefault">-->
    <!--      <Arg><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>-->
    <!--      <Call name="addBefore">-->
    <!--        <Arg name="beforeClass">org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Arg>-->
    <!--        <Arg>-->
    <!--          <Array type="String">-->
    <!--            <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration</Item>-->
    <!--          </Array>-->
    <!--        </Arg>-->
    <!--      </Call>-->
    <!--    </Call>-->

    <Get id="oldhandler" name="handler"/>
    <Set name="handler">
        <New id="DebugHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DebugHandler">
            <Set name="handler"><Ref refid="oldhandler"/></Set>
            <Set name="outputStream">
                <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.RolloverFileOutputStream">
                    <Arg type="String"><Property name="jetty.logs" default="./log"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.debug.log</Arg>
                    <Arg type="boolean">true</Arg> <!-- append -->
                    <Arg type="int">90</Arg> <!-- retain days -->
                </New>
            </Set>
        </New>
    </Set>

    <!--    <Set name="handler">-->
    <!--      <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">-->
    <!--        <Set name="handlers">-->
    <!--        <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">-->
    <!--            <Item>-->
    <!--            <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>-->
    <!--            </Item>-->
    <!--            <Item>-->
    <!--            <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>-->
    <!--            </Item>-->
    <!--            <Item>-->
    <!--            <New id="RequestLog" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler"/>-->
    <!--            </Item>-->
    <!--        </Array>-->
    <!--        </Set>-->
    <!--      </New>-->
    <!--    </Set>-->

    <!-- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16416   -->
    <!--  https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-9/org/eclipse/jetty/server/NCSARequestLog.html#field.summary  -->
    <!--  https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-9/org/eclipse/jetty/server/CustomRequestLog.html  -->

    <Set name="requestLog">
        <New id="RequestLog" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.CustomRequestLog">
            <Arg>
                <SystemProperty name="jetty.logs" default="./log"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log
            </Arg>
            <Arg>Extended</Arg>
        </New>
    </Set>
    <Call name="addBean">
        <Arg>

            <New id="DeploymentManager" class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager">
                <Set name="contexts">
                    <Ref refid="Contexts" />
                </Set>

                <Call name="addAppProvider">
                    <Arg>
                        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ContextProvider">
                            <Set name="monitoredDirName">
                                <Property>
                                    <Name>jetty.deploy.monitoredPath</Name>
                                    <Default>
                                        <Property name="jetty.base" default="." />/<Property name="jetty.deploy.monitoredDir" deprecated="jetty.deploy.monitoredDirName" default="webapps"/>
                                    </Default>
                                </Property>
                            </Set>
                            <Set name="defaultsDescriptor">
                                <Property>
                                    <Name>jetty.deploy.defaultsDescriptorPath</Name>
                                    <Default>
                                        <Property name="jetty.home" default="." />./cfg/webdefault.xml
                                    </Default>
                                </Property>
                            </Set>
                            <Set name="scanInterval">
                                <Property name="jetty.deploy.scanInterval" default="1"/>
                            </Set>
                            <Set name="extractWars">
                                <Property name="jetty.deploy.extractWars" default="true"/>
                            </Set>

                        </New>
                    </Arg>
                </Call>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>

Muchas gracias, espero que me den su ayuda en esto.
Creo que el error viene de las nuevas modificaciones a la clase ScanningAppProvider de jetty, producto del cambio de version. modificaron muchas cosas

Es un poco raro, se supone que no está configurado  DeploymentManager, pero veo que esta dentro de jetty.xml

si quieres te paso el codigo completo

ok, si por favor @BAUTISTABASILIO

https://github.com/Bautistadev/rest-jpos-jetty

Solo necesito que muestre los endpoint y el el swagger que tiene integrado, desde el viernes pasado que lucho con esto ajaj
